# Hooking PHP into Apache Server is not working

Tags: php, windows, apache

My operating system is Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

I have 32-bit Apache Server 2.2 version installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2` folder listening on port 81 as a service and it is working ok.

I also have 32-bit PHP 5.5.20 Thread Safe version working ok:

- I downloaded 32-bit PHP 5.5.20 Thread Safe version
- unzip it in `C:\DevPrograms\php-5.5.20-Win32-VC11-x86` folder
- copy the php.ini-development file to the same folder and rename it to php.ini file
- unremark the `extension_dir = "ext"` row in php.ini file
- include the `C:\DevPrograms\php-5.5.20-Win32-VC11-x86` in the **path** system variable
- run `php -v` on command prompt and it works ok.

Now I am trying to hook up PHP into Apache Server.

In my `C:\DevPrograms\php-5.5.20-Win32-VC11-x86` folder there is a file php5apache2_4.dll

I open the httpd.conf file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf` folder for modification:

Include these lines after the last #LoadModule row

```
# For PHP 5 do something like this:
LoadModule php5_module "C:/DevPrograms/php-5.5.20-Win32-VC11-x86/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

# configure the path to php.ini
PHPIniDir "C:/DevPrograms/php-5.5.20-Win32-VC11-x86"
```

Save the httpd.conf file and then in the Apache Service Monitor window, restart the Apache2.2 Server. But I get an error message:

### The requested operation has failed!

Why it is failing? Is it because of version incompatibility?

Comment: If your server is 64-bit why are you downloading the 32-bit version of everything?  That didn't strike you as the wrong thing to do?

Comment: I have run onto problems with 64-bit version of softwares so I try to go with 32-bit version of software as much as possible. In this case Apache and PHP are both 32-bit so I believe it is not an issue. The issue might be that PHP 5.5.20 is not backward compatible with Apache 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution. Basically PHP 5.5.20 is not backward compatible with Apache 2.2.25 as I suspect. So I downgraded PHP to PHP 5.4.36 and then it works ok with Apache 2.2.25.